# How to implement horizontal scrollable list using ListView.Builder or ListView.Seperated widget?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make horizontal scrollable list from the arry having multiple datas, such as name, imgaeUrl, Time.

I created array of FoodItems and inside of arrya i have different data ,

```
arrFoodItem = [{  "name": "Classic Green Salad 1","Time": "16","imageUrl": "assets/greenSalad.png"}]
```

here is my code

> ```
> import 'package:foodrecipe/components/foodColor.dart';
> class FoodItems extends StatelessWidget {
>
>   FoodItems({
>     super.key,
>   });
>   final List<Map> arrFoodItems = [
>     {
>       "name": "Classic Green Salad 1",
>       "Time": "16",
>       "imageUrl": "assets/greenSalad.png"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "Classic Green Salad 2",
>       "Time": "17",
>       "imageUrl": "assets/greenSalad.png"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "Classic Green Salad 3",
>       "Time": "18",
>       "imageUrl": "assets/greenSalad.png"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "Classic Green Salad 4",
>       "Time": "19",
>       "imageUrl": "assets/greenSalad.png"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "Classic Green Salad 5",
>       "Time": "20",
>       "imageUrl": "assets/greenSalad.png"
>     },
>   ];
>
> @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return SizedBox(
>       height: 250.0,
>       // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
>       child: Stack(
>         clipBehavior: Clip.none,
>         children: [
>           Container(
>             decoration: BoxDecoration(
>               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
>               color: FoodColor.colourStylesNeutralColourGray4,
>             ),
>             height: 250.0,
>             width: 500.0,
>             child: ListView.separated(
>                 // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>                 itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
>                   return ListTile(
>                       leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
>                       title: Text(arrFoodItems[index]["name"]),
>                       subtitle: Text(arrFoodItems[index]['Time']));
>                 }),
>                 separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
>                       color: FoodColor.colourStylesPrimaryColourPrimary60,
>                       thickness: 5.0,
>                     ),
>                 itemCount: arrFoodItems.length),),
>
>         ],
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: error: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#72a05 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `ListTile()`, the widget has no fixed width size. You need to change the widget you are using to another one. or still you want to use `ListTile`. you need to give width size by yourself with `Constraints`.

Comment: I thought I wrapped that ListView.Separated with a return SizedBox() and no need to wrap the ListTile. thanks for the help man.